# IMO 2015 warm up problem

Tags: inequality, contest-math, arithmetic-combinatorics

I get this problem from IMO 2015 facebook page. Let $x_i$ be positive integers for $i=1,2,...,11$. If $x_i+x_{i+1}\geq 100$, $|x_i-x_{i+1}|\geq 20$ for $i=1,2,...,10$. And $x_{11}+x_{1}\geq 100$, $|x_{11}-x_1|\geq 20$. What is the minimum possible value of $\sum_{i=1}^{11}x_i$ ? 
Thanks for solutions.

Comment: I know this is contest math but do let us know your own thoughts,ideas anyway.

Comment: It same to write 11 positive integer on circumference. Sum of successive number are $\geq 100$ and difference are $\geq 20$.

Comment: get $\sum x_i\geq 550$. But i think this is not the minimum.

Answer (score 3):

**The minimum sum is 580**. Imagine that $x_1, x_2, ..., x_{11}$ are placed around a circle. By summing consecutive pairs starting at $x_{j+1}$ we notice that $\sum x_i \geq 500 + x_j$. So letting $x^* = \max_i\{x_i\}$ we have

$$ \sum x_i \geq 500 + x^* $$

First we note that $x^* \geq 60$ because if not, its neighbors cannot possibly satisfy the constraints. Next we prove that $x^* \geq 80$. Suppose NOT and WLOG let $x_1 = x^*$. By the constraints and the bounds on $x^*$, we find

$$x_1 \in [60,80) \implies x_2 \in (20,60)  \implies \\ x_3 \in [60,80) \implies \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; ... \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\implies \\ x_{11} \in [60,80) \implies x_1 \in (20,60) \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$$

a contradiction (the two $\implies$ are fairly obvious so I leave the gritty details to you). So we've shown that $\sum x_i \geq 580$. The assignment 80, 60, 40, 60, 40, 60, 40, 60, 40, 60, 40 proves that the bound is tight.